# preventing Rx/Tx data clashing on a xmega USART

Tags: uart, interrupts, xmega

I am using the USART module on an atxmega128a1 to communicate with a PC, and I've noticed that receiving and transmitting a byte uses the same data register address:
[image: USART data register]

My question is then, if I am in the middle of transmitting a byte OUT of this data register, how do I prevent an interrupt triggered by a byte coming IN from causing me to lose data?

My current code uses Rx and Tx software FIFO buffers, an interrupt to trigger a byte received and a timer interrupt to output a byte periodically from my TxFIFO:

```
//interrupt to receive a byte (RS232)
ISR(USARTD0_RXC_vect){                          //ISR for when receive flag is set
    if(FIFO_Put(&RxFIFO, USARTD0_DATA)){        //put data into receive FIFO
        USARTD0_STATUS |= USART_RXCIF_bm;       //write 1 to clear bit
    }
    while(!(USARTD1_STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm));  //wait until data register is empty
}

ISR(TCC1_OVF_vect){
    unsigned char data;
    if(FIFO_Get(&TxFIFO, &data)){                   //place a byte from FIFO into &data
        while(!(USARTD1_STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm));  //if Tx FIFO has data, wait until data register is empty
        USARTD0_DATA = data;                        //put it in the data buffer
        while(!(USARTD0_STATUS & USART_TXCIF_bm));  //wait until transfer complete
        USARTD0_STATUS |= USART_TXCIF_bm;           //write 1 to clear bit
    }
}
```

BOTH of these interrupts are "low" priority and round robin servicing of interrupts are enabled. I want to increase the period of the timer interrupt but anything faster than 5ms interrupts causes data to be lost. I would use RTS/CTS but I want to know what my options are first as I believe the xmega is capable of doing what I want without data loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is then, if I am in the middle of transmitting a byte OUT of this data register, how do I prevent an interrupt triggered by a byte coming IN from causing me to lose data?

You don't. There are two separate registers, accessed using the *same* address but *different* modes. One holds the last byte pulled from the receive hardware, and the other holds the next byte to put into the transmit hardware.

If you read from `DATA` you access `RXB`, and if you write to `DATA` you access `TXB`.

Comment: Could you shed some light as to why I may be losing data?

the baud rate is 19200 which equates to 512us per byte being placed into DATA(RXB) - but I cannot output 1 byte from DATA(TXB) quicker than a 5ms interrupt?

Do i have to do more flag checking? What sort of procedure would you recommend??

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was wrong - My timer interrupt needed to be disabled during my "FIFO_Get" and "FIFO_Put" functions.

What was happening was the timer was interrupting whilst in the middle of these functions which corrupts the data being output.

The above code is correct, and thank you to @Ignacio for helping me realize the issue lie elsewhere.